# Wordpress tinyMCE Custom Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I'm just getting into plugin development in Wordpress. Right now I have a function that a I pass as a filter to the 'tiny_mce_before_init' with specific variables to change the buttons, add custom styling and other similar things.

I'm in the process of building a an Options Page which I would like to control the variables passed to the tinyMCE function, that way the user can select which buttons to display as well as add a custom stylesheet to the editor.

At this point, my function to edit the tiny mce works great! and the options page is also saving data, checkboxes and everything else I need.

My only issue is I'm not understanding how to pass the variables stored in the "options.php" to the current tinyMCE function. This is the current function in my functions.php file:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    //styles for the editor to provide better visual representation.
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
    $in['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 1=h1; Heading 2=h2";
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'formatselect,bold,italic,underline,superscript,bullist,numlist,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,spellchecker';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

I don't want to convolute the post by adding all the code of my Options Page, but I might need some direction on how to approach on passing variables as the value of the $in[]. As mentioned before, the variables would be created in an Options Page and saved, updating the tiny mce function.

I've researched a lot and I can't find any direct information on this -- as usual, I'm not looking for somebody to do my code but maybe to push me in the right direction.

Thanks!

**EDIT NEW CODE**

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_cool_plugin_create_menu');

function my_cool_plugin_create_menu() {
    add_menu_page('My Cool Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
}

function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
}

function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Your Plugin Name</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name') ); ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }

function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {

    $toolbar = get_option('new_option_name');

    //styles for the editor to provide better visual representation.
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
    $in['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 1=h1; Heading 2=h2";
    $in['toolbar1'] = $toolbar;
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    return $in;
}
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
?>
```

I'm still having difficulty accessing the stored variables and using them in the function. Any ideas?

Comment: Save them to the options table, retrieve them within filter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Can you elaborate more detail please! Should I use apply_filter()? thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your options page, you can save options with [update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option). Then, in your `my_format_TinyMCE` function, you can access them with [get_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Comment: Thank you @Flyer -- this is the approach that makes more sense, but I'm having difficulty with it. I'm updating my code to show the full context. Thank you!

Comment: @mmarquez I think you haven't properly initiated stuff with settings. Refer to [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) for information and examples

Comment: The problem was trying to use the $variable = get_option() but If I use just the get_option() as the variable, it works fine. Your answer is the correct one -- and your link is very useful. thank you!